# execlp "sort" with input from pipe stucks, why?

Tags: pipe, c, file-descriptors

`sort` is waiting, but what?  I tried `execlp("head", "head", "-n", "3", NULL);` instead `sort` and it works fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
  int p[2], cat_pid, sort_pid;
  if (pipe(p) < 0) { assert(0 && "pipe fail"); }
  if ((cat_pid = fork()) == 0) { dup2(p[1], 1); execlp("cat", "cat", "text", NULL); assert(0 && "cat fail"); }
  if ((sort_pid = fork()) == 0) { dup2(p[0], 0); execlp("sort", "sort", NULL); assert(0 && "sort fail"); }
  waitpid(sort_pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

input `text` is:

```
hello
world
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `sort` is waiting for EOF you need to close pipe' write end. One is closed once `cat` is done and another one is in parent process. Close pipe' write end in parent and everything should go fine.

`man 7 pipe`

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).

Comment: Note: if `p[1]` was closed AFTER sort's fork, this fork needs to close it itself! I got it, TY!